# QPlainTextEdit force redraw

Tags: qt, widget, syntax-highlighting, qwidget, qtextedit

I'd like to force a redraw over a QPlainTextEdit widget, because my highlighting rules changed. However, all lines and blocks aren't redrawn, respecting the new rules.

This is true because if I modify a line, the correct highlighting is applied, and I am happy. But I cannot force-modify each block to see any change!

Is there a way to force a redraw? I tried update() and similars, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call [`QSyntaxHighlighter::rehighlight()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qsyntaxhighlighter.html#rehighlight) to apply the new highlighting rules to the whole document.

Comment: Yes! This seems the cleanest of the solutions.

Answer (score 7):

QPlainTextEdit inherits QAbstractScrollArea, so its content is located in viewport widget. Try this:

```
text_edit->viewport()->update();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
text_edit->repaint();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case simply calling rehighlight don't update view. In my case i want update highlight when cursor moves so:

```
void MyHighlighter::onSelectionChanged(int start, int end)
{
    _visibleCursor.setPosition(end);
    document()->documentLayout()->updateBlock(_visibleCursor.block());
    rehighlightBlock(_visibleCursor.block());
}
```